# Can we get a link to site stats for betas, placed on the main sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, statistics

During a beta period, many users find that it's significant to monitor the site's statistics.  Site statistics for the betas (and ratings of those statistics) are available on Area51.  However, if you joined a beta late in the game (I think the cutoff is after it goes public) then there is no link to the site statistics page in your Area51 profile.  The only way to get to that page then, is to search for it.

Could we get a link to the stats page included in the main sites, at least for betas?

Comment: I imagine that using the Site Stats banner on the right sidebar would be a good place to link it. It already carries some of the statistics themselves, but not the ratings of those statistics.

Comment: @Grace unfortunately those statistics aren't computed using the same methods, visitors/day in particular.  I don't understand why that hasn't been updated.

Comment: @Grace - As you've mentioned, the banner also does not give the ratings of those statistics.  I agree that it would be a good place for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

See links in the footer of the Site Stats panel on the homepage of any beta site.

Comment: Nice to see this fixed, but it's now another one of those relatively obscure features.  Looking at the links there, I'd initially thought they only pointed to the Area 51 and StackExchange homepages - they don't appear (until on mouseover, and inspection of the target) to have any specific relevance to the beta site itself.

Comment: @iszi the title of this post is "Can we get a link to site stats for betas, placed on the main sites?" and we now have links *exactly* as described in your title. What's 'obscure' about that?

Comment: The link text/image, as I've stated, does not clearly identify its true purpose.  Again, the casual observer will most likely only interpret them to be meant for the Area 51 and StackExchange homepages - not the site-specific detail pages for which they're actually used.  Perhaps a text above the links, saying "See additional stats on:" or something similar could help clear this up.