# How can I easily see the progress of a Beta site?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a link to site stats for betas, placed on the main sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76945/can-we-get-a-link-to-site-stats-for-betas-placed-on-the-main-sites)

At [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) you can easily see the progress of a Beta site. For example, the **[Science Fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)** site's progress can be seen here: **[Science Fiction progress](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction)**.

But there is no clear link (that I am aware of) from the *beta site* to this *progress indicator* at Area 51.

**Suggestion:** add a link from *every* beta site to their own Area 51 progress page. Or move the progress page from Area 51 to the Beta. Either way, make it *one click away*.

**Rationale:** continuous feedback of status encourages beta sites and helps them to see what they need to do to improve, e.g. should they focus on more followers or more answers to questions?

Comment: I asked [a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70396/can-we-have-a-link-to-the-area51-proposal-on-beta-sites), but my intent was a convenient link to the site's definition phase. It doesn't look promising that it will be implemented.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76945/can-we-get-a-link-to-site-stats-for-betas-placed-on-the-main-sites